# Ajax method "Undefined error " on webpage?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, iis, iis-7

Ajax functionality not working on the web page getting "undefined error" in ASP.Net?how to solve this error?I try to add following in webconfig,

```
<httphandler>
    <add verb="GET"  path="ScriptResource.axd"  type="Microsoft.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler" validate="false"/>
<httphandler>.
```

Still I get the same error.what are the resons for getting the undefined error and how to fix this?My asp website is configured in IIS 7.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you added latest jquery.js to your web page before calling ajax ?